# Generate automated daily status report email from VSTS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, status

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate version.I have created User stories and added tasks against them .Now I need to generate automated daily status email reports  showing daily progress on tasks.
How can I do this ,please point me to to some step by step tutorials to configure this.
Do I need any special admin privileges in TFS ?

I went to visualStudio2013 team explorer and reports>>Project Mgmt>>Stories Overview

I can see that report ,but my question is how can I configure an email task that will automatically get that report and send to the team everyday ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out if you are using an on-premise TFS server or using Visual Studio Online. If you are using VSO then you can use the REST API to query work items and create the status report yourseld. Have a look at [Get started with the VSO REST APIs](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/get-started-rest-basics-vsi). You should use OAuth for authorization, but you can use basic authentication. Check [Authentication for the REST APIs](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/get-started-auth-introduction-vsi).

Answer (score 0):

With an on-premeses installation of TFS you get optional reporting infrastructure.

http://nakedalm.com/integrate-reporting-and-analyses-services-with-team-foundation-server-2013/

With this installed you can use the out of the box reports to do what you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380648.aspx

The Stories Overview report gives you completeness and you can have it emailed as a pdf daily if you wish.

Comment: I can see that report team explorer and reports>>Project Mgmt>>Stories Overview ,but my question is how can I configure an email task that will automatically get that report and send to the team everyday ?